# AngularJS automated routes

Tags: php, angularjs

I use a lightweight PHP framework at my job which uses an MVC architecture, so most URL's are built like  `/controller/action/`. I am currently in between using the same PHP framework and AngularJS + REST API in a project I am about to start developing on my free time. I've already familiarized myself with the basics of AngularJS and built a structure + authentication with tokens.

I already created a route by splitting window.location.href, but when a controller needs parameters, it should be something like a wildcard. Can this be done? Or are we stuck to manually creating all route params?

```
.when('/' + controller + '/' + action, {
        templateUrl: '/assets/layouts/' + controller + '/' + action+ '.html',
        controller: controller + methodPath
    })
```

Edit: controller is not nescessary if you init it in the view element, but methodPath is just method with the first letter capitalized so creating a controller as usersRegister, path is /users/register

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I figured it out. I just find out the rest of the path and include them in the `when`. This is a rough example and should be extended to set a default method if one is not found, such as  `main` or `index`.

```
var location = window.location.href;
var arguments = location.split('/');

if(arguments.length > 4) {
    var module = arguments[3];
    var method = arguments[4];

    var methodPath = method.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + method.slice(1);
}

var routeparams = [];

for(var i = 5, x = 0; i < arguments.length; i++, x++) {
    var argument = ':param' + x;
    routeparams.push(argument);
}

routeparams = routeparams.join('/');

$routeProvider.
    when('/' + module + '/' + method + '/' + routeparams, {
        templateUrl: '/assets/layouts/' + module + '/' + method + '.html',
        controller: module + methodPath
    })
```

Now I can access parameters in the Controller with

```
usersModule.controller('usersRegister', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) { 
    $scope.uid = $routeParams.param0; 
}
```